# Postman works but fetch() doesnt. Why not?

Tags: javascript, express, fetch

Postman request seems to work but i cannot get fetch() to work with the same request & headers. Its driving me nuts.

Client:

```
fetch('http://localhost:1234/acts/create', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        name: 'BARNEY MCGREW!',
        rating: 90,
    })
})
```

Express:

```
exports.act_create = function (req, res) {
    console.log(' req >>>>', req.body);
    var act = new Act(
        {
            name: req.body.name,
            rating: req.body.rating
        }
    );

    // res.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    act.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        res.send('Act Created successfully')
    })
};
```

This generates the following terminal output:

```
 req >>>> :  [Object: null prototype] { '{"name":"IngleburtHumperdink","rating":10}': '' }
act is:  { _id: 5c4245bea7bb511c20de6b7a }
```

So it's sort of coming through but then i get `ValidationError: Act validation failed: name: Path`name`is required., rating: Path "rating" is required.`

Same for path "name".

So it's obv struggling to match the json stringified object with a name/rating value coming in. But removing the JSON.stringify from the body of the POST request gets me a `req >>>> [Object: null prototype] { '[object Object]': '' }`

**What am i doing wrong here?**

[and are there any good blogs where they clearly explain how to pass data through body so it's accessible via `fetch()` without issue? ]

Comment: Where are you call `fetch`? A console of that local page? Please show error when use fetch in Network tab in devtools

Comment: Are you using [body-parser middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)?

Comment: @Ｈｏｎｇａｒｃ  Yes using fetch to call a Mongo/Mlab express point. So it's in a chrome browser dev tools console.  it just hangs on `Promise {<pending>}` 
And yes, @Oscar i have bodyParser set in my app.js  `app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));` - i've been following this tutorial so it's all the same except `products` are `acts`. 

Comment: @NewbieAid what's the output if you try to log `req.body.name` in your console?

Comment: It will log undefined – when `req.body` is logged, we can see it's an object containing only one key, and that key happens to be the entire stringified JSON.

Comment: @Oscar 'undefined'. It's like it can't quite get to the value that's visible stringified in `req.body`

Comment: @Callam adding null and 2 hasn't changed anything. ☹️ Tryihng application/json now but i gather that creates cors issues, no?

Comment: @NewbieAid it shouldn't if you're using `fetch` on the same domain. I've reproduced your issue and it works fine if you set the correct content-type

Comment: @Oscar my server is running on localhost 1234. My chrome console is just an `about: blank` page. But I've also run it from localhost:3000 (my webapp i'm trying to use it on) and it fails too. Setting content type to application/json on the fetch request immediately generates a cors issue. 

Comment: @NewbieAid replace `JSON.stringify` with `new URLSearchParams`.

Answer (score 5):

The `x-www-form-urlencoded` request body must be `name=BARNEY%20MCGREW%21&rating=90`.

You send a request by `fetch` with the body `'{"name":"BARNEY MCGREW!","rating":90}'`.

Since there is no `=`, the entire JSON string is considered a parameter name with an empty value.

So you are given an object from the `req.body` where the stringified JSON appears as a key.

---

Create `URLSearchParams` by passing your data to the constructor – replace `JSON.stringify`.

```
fetch('http://localhost:1234/acts/create', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
    body: new URLSearchParams({
        name: 'BARNEY MCGREW!',
        rating: 90,
    })
})
```

Your `fetch` request body should now be `name=BARNEY%20MCGREW%21&rating=90`.

This will be correctly parsed by the body parser as `x-www-form-urlencoded` content.

---

If `URLSearchParams` is undefined, there are npm packages that will provide it. Otherwise, all it is doing is constructing a URL Params string by encoding and joining the keys and values with a `=`, and joining each pair with an `&`, which can be done like so:

```
function URLSearchParams(data) {
    return Object.keys(data).map(key => {
        return `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(data[key])}`;
    }).join('&');
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Callum  So this is _almost_ there.. i'm now getting the confirmation in my terminal & MLab is saving the new entry, but in the Chrome console it's flagging CORS which i thought was a non-issue for `x-www-form-urlencoded` ?
Also my web app does the same. Flags CORS but it gets through to MLAB? Confused?

Comment: @NewbieAid in what aspect is it flagging CORS? Do you get a specific message?

Comment: different port numbers, possibly the issue:
`home:1 Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:1234/acts/create' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS` - is there a quick/easy way of setting no-cors using express.Router - couldn't find anything last night when i was trying to fix this.

Comment: For testing, add the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to your server responses and set it to  `http://localhost:3000`. Should look something like this `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000")`